# Swift 4.2 Compiling Vapor 2.4.5 On Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: swift, ubuntu, vapor

I have a program that I deploy onto Ubuntu (Vapor 2.4.5 based server app). Up to this point it's been compiling under Swift 4.1 without issue.

Today, I applied a few patches to my UAT server (hosted on AWS). I noticed  Swift got updated to 4.2. Now the Swift build process fails, with the following message:

> swift: /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.2-package-linux-ubuntu-16_04/llvm/lib/IR/Instructions.cpp:2565: static llvm::CastInst *llvm::CastInst::Create(Instruction::CastOps, llvm::Value *, llvm::Type *, const llvm::Twine &, llvm::Instruction *): Assertion `castIsValid(op, S, Ty) && "Invalid cast!"' failed.

Any ideas what this might be?

I rolled my server back to its prior state, and no problems the code compiles.

Phil

Comment: That's a Swift compiler bug. If you wouldn't mind, please file at https://bugs.swift.org :)

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch - have logged a JIRA.